# How to embed Apache derby inside a web application

Tags: java, web-applications, derby

I just started developing a web-application. I'd like to use Apache derby as a database packaged inside my web-application.
Here is the list of jars I am using

> derby.jar,
>   derbyclient.jar,
>   derbynet.jar,
>   derbytools.jar

I'm unable to establish connection.
Code snippet is here

```
//start the server
NetworkServerControl networkServerControl= new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),1527);
networkServerControl.start(null);
//establish connection & create database
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LoginDB;create=true");
```

It's throwing this exception

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LoginDB;create=true
```

I have placed all the libraries inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of my web application. How to get a connection?

**Update:**

Adding more detail

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/LoginDB;create=true
Jan 05, 2013 10:41:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ReadProperty] in context with path [/Question] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.humbledevelopers.question.DerbyDemo.main(DerbyDemo.java:96)
```

code at Line 96: `statement=connection.createStatement();`

Comment: It certainly does not look as if the JDBC driver jar is in fact in WEB-INF/lib. Are you perfectly sure?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that, all the above 4 jars are a part of  WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Please edit your post with more details of the exception. What's the exception class and backtrace?

Comment: post updated, please tell if it's not clear

Comment: Just to clarify another point: are you running a derby server somewhere, or are you just trying to use it in fully-embedded mode? If the later, you don't want that 'localhost' in there.

Comment: Oh! Derby server is present locally and its fully-embedded mode.

Comment: In that case, have you read : http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/rdevdvlp22102.html#rdevdvlp22102?

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864443/packing-embedded-database-in-jar-file/11867360#11867360)

Comment: What version of Java are you running? If it is JDK 1.5 or earlier, you may need to call Class.forName() to register the Derby client driver with the DriverManager class.

Comment: My java verison: JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to connect to derby using tcp connection if you are trying to run derby as a part of application.

[Get More Details here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html)

Comment: True, but not relevant to not finding the JDBC driver at all.