# Java SQL error, no suitable driver found

Tags: java, database, netbeans, database-connection, derby

I'm trying to compile this small piece of code, to help me connect to my db and retrieve some information to test it. I am using Netbeans on a Windows 7 x64 machine. This is the code:

```
package passwordprotector;
import java.sql.*;

public class PasswordProtector {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PasswordProtector DB";
    String dbUsername = "john"; 
    String dbPassword = "arsenal";

    /*try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }*/

    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, dbUsername, dbPassword);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM APP.PERSON");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String uName = rs.getString("uname");
            String uPass = rs.getString("upass");
            System.out.println("Username: " + uName + "/n" + "Password: " + uPass);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

When I compile and run I receive this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PasswordProtector DB
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

When I right click on my db and select properties I can see it's location, like so:

```
Database URL: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PasswordProtector
```

I've checked with others who have posted about this and it seems they had an incorrect URL as the issue, but I can't see any other URL which I can use apart from the one posted.

I've tried with and without the ending ' DB' for the String host, neither works.

I've also already read from [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html) and still couldn't figure out why the URl is incorrect:

Comment: Why did you comment the loading driver?

Comment: I read that it wasn't needed for Java 6 upwards as stated here (top answer)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111534/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-sinusoide-db

I've tried both with and without. Neither work.

Comment: This is what I get:
run:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the problem with the database URL connection, but in the usage of the correct driver. If the database is embedded you should use the driver commented in your post and example from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864443/packing-embedded-database-in-jar-file/11867360#11867360), there's also [tutorial embedded derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html).

if not then use

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
```

It's a different driver to connect to the database running standalone. In this case see [derby network client](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyClientSpec.html) documentation how to configure and run derby network client.

Comment: I'm not sure if the driver is embedded or not if I'm being honest. I've tried using your answer and I get:
run: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver but I've also used ClientDriver instead of EmbeddedDriver in my code and neither works.

Comment: How do you run, I need to know if are you running embedded or not?

Comment: Do you start the derby database separately when you run your app or not?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check but I think this answers your question - when opening Netbeans for the first time I must right click the db and select 'Connect...'. This is a new project and I have no actual runnable classes yet.

Comment: @JohnVasiliou can i have acces to your system/DB ?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou Then you need a client driver, check the last part of the answer. In your app you need to change the driver class.

Comment: Thanks, I went through your code very slowly and understood it, I then altered it accordingly after putting derbyrun.jar in my classpath and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure derbyrun.jar is in your classpath.  It resides in the db/lib directory of your JDK.

Comment: I have done this, I have added derbyrun.jar into my classpath. Within Netbeans I right clicked on my project, properties, library, add jar and added the correct file - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search on Maven and Derby, included the following in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and everything worked afterwards, so it may be a library reference issue if the previous solution did not work.