# Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found. When trying to connect to db

Tags: java, database, netbeans, javadb

I have set up a project in Netbeans, created a script, made a new database with javadb. I can connect to it by gui - display the tables contents etc, but when i run an application with:

```
 EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("lab5PU").createEntityManager();
```

i get this quite long exception:

```
[EL Info]: 2013-04-05 21:40:45.554--ServerSession(1198260109)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504
[EL Severe]: 2013-04-05 21:40:45.574--ServerSession(1198260109)--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found.
Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:82)
```

I can see the javadb drivers in the driver section in services, so i have no idea what the error might be.

EDIT: persistance.xml as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="lab5PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>lab5.Colleagues</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/lab5"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypass"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[image]

Comment: Where your db connection is configured? In `persistence.xml`? Can you show that configuration?

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała added persistance.xml as requested

Comment: I'm new in JEE but this driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` works for my application.

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: changing it to your driver, caused an unexpected driver error.

Comment: @jalopaba NetBeans IDE 7.1 (Build 201112071828)

Comment: How do you run the db?

Comment: @RomanC netbeans runs it for me i think. I can connect to it via gui, and excecute scripts, so i think its there.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski So, what the driver your GUI uses to connect to the db?

Comment: @RomanC in connection properties it says it is the same driver - org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Ok, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547109/java-sql-error-no-suitable-driver-found/14547321#14547321

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27665/discussion-between-bartlomiej-lewandowski-and-roman-c)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the problem you have is that you don't have the Derby driver in the classpath of the project.

You can easily achieve that adding the JavaDB library to your project:

- Right-click on the project
- Properties ->  Libraries
- Add Library -> JavaDB driver

This includes `derby.jar`, `derbyclient.jar` and `derbynet.jar` in your project's classpath.

The `derbyclient.jar` contains the class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` your code is complaining about.

Comment: i do not have an option to select that libary, i have downloaded the derby libs, where should i put them?

Comment: Sorry, it is not "Java DB" but "Java DB Driver"... (in NetBeans 7.3)