# Java Netbeans producing persistence error on different system

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence

I have virtually completed a basic database management application in Netbeans, saved to and running off a flash drive. Unfortunately, the main computer I was using broke down, now I would like to run the program on another system, however, am getting a persistence error that has left me completely lost (despite following what I believed to be the right steps to allow the program to run off the drive on another computer at the beginning). The database is located on and saved to the flash drive. Can anyone help? I have tried altering the address name in the persistence.xml file to no avail.

This is the error:

> [EL Info]: 2018-10-03
>   16:07:22.109--ServerSession(2101086700)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd [EL Severe]: ejb:
>   2018-10-03 16:07:22.116--ServerSession(2101086700)--Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception in
>   thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Configuration error.  Class
>   [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found. Exception
>   Description: Configuration error.  Class
>   [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found.     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
>     at datsneakers.DisplayGUI.initComponents(DisplayGUI.java:69)    at
>   datsneakers.DisplayGUI.(DisplayGUI.java:42)     at
>   datsneakers.DatSneakers.main(DatSneakers.java:6) Caused by: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Configuration error.  Class
>   [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found.     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.configurationErrorClassNotFound(DatabaseException.java:89)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.loadDriverClass(DefaultConnector.java:267)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
>     ... 7 more

Please bear with me, I am a relatively amateur programmer. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver not found. When trying to connect to db](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15842229/2985643). The error reported in your stack trace is _Configuration error. Class [org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver] not found_. Is it possible that you are still referencing the Derby driver on the computer that broke down? If so, the accepted answer in the linked question explains how to resolve that.

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver. Thank you.