# Access derby database in executable jar

Tags: java, derby

I have been looking for a while now but haven't found exactly what I want. So, I have a project written in Java and have created a small Derby database that I have embedded in the project. Now when creating an executable jar of the project, I cannot access the database anymore unless I put the derby database files in the same directory of where the executable jar is located. However, I do not want this, I really want that the database files are INSIDE the jar.

I have tried to put the database files in a package and reference it like that, without any luck. Could someone point out how I can get this to work please?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
The goal here is that I want to create more than one executable JAR file and upload them to a Sun Grid Engine and execute each jar with different parameters. However, they all need to be able to access the database and until now I get an error when 1 application already booted the derby database, another application cannot access it. Therefor ALL jar files need to have their own database.

Comment: Is it a readonly database, or do you intend to update it from within you application?

Comment: It is a readonly database

Comment: And extracting it to some temp directory and deleting it when you close the application is not an option?

Comment: The link you gave me (and already deleted) said this: "The database should be in the folder where you runs the jar." which is exactly what I do not want. - I added to the original post what my goal is here.

Comment: I didn't link that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864443/packing-embedded-database-in-jar-file) but I did have a look at it. The key could be in the "check docs how to specify connection url". It could be possible. The jar is just a zip. A connection url can address the contents of the jar. I vaguely remember doing something like that to access some bitmaps and resources without extracting them.

Comment: How about this? [https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp24155.html#cdevdvlp24155](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp24155.html#cdevdvlp24155)

Comment: Exactly something like that. I had a bit of a hard time finding the right url to make it work, but it did. And this is somewhat useful for other things... just consider that many other formats are just renamed zipped containers (epub, docx, xlsx).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the jdbc:derby:jar protocol to access your database?

According to the [documentation](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/devguide/cdevdeploy15325.html) what you're after should be possible.

Inside your app (the one going into the executable jar) you must access the database using the jdbc:derby:jar protocol.

Create the database with the desired content.
When you have built your jar, you can use jar commands to add the database dir to your jar.

All of this could go in your build script, obviously..

There may be issues related to jar sealing and such, YMMV.